react-select-country-list return Error: Minified React error #31
import React, { useState, useMemo } from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'
import countryList from 'react-select-country-list'    

export const Profile = () => {
    const [citizenship, setCitizenship] = useState("");

    async function save() {
        fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_IP}/api/updateProfile`, {
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            method: "PUT",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                citizenship: citizenship.label
            }),
        })
    }    

    const options = useMemo(() => countryList().getData(), []);

    const changeHandler = (country) => {
        setCitizenship(country)
    }

    return (
        <Select
           options={options}
           value={citizenship}
           onChange={changeHandler}                     
        />  
    )                       
}

I'm using react-select-country-list to select country for citizenship form. Why does this return Minified React error #31 when I run async function save()? What is false with my code? How to fix it?
